# Complie with -fPIC error while installing cvxopt for python 3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, python-3.x, cvxopt

I am trying to install cvxopt using the git option provided in the cvxopt documentation. When I run

```
..:~/cvxopt/$ python3 setup.py install
```

I get the following error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/C/umfpack.o -lumfpack -lcholmod -lamd -lcolamd -lsuitesparseconfig -llapack -lblas -lrt -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cvxopt/umfpack.cpython-34m.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuitesparseconfig.a(SuiteSparse_config.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

what to do about this?